Возможно ли воспроизвести аудиофайл после получения разрешения пользователя на воспроизведение аудио 1 раз?
Я пытаюсь воспроизвести аудио без взаимодействия с пользователем и получаю ошибку:
"Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play method is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission."

Вот мой код:
<audio id="beep"> <source src="~/Content/Sounds/beep.mp3" type="audio/mp3"> </audio>
 <script> 
      var playAudio = $("#beep")[0]; 
      playAudio.play(); 
</script>

Как я понимаю, это запрещено текущими браузерами воспроизводить аудио без явного взаимодействия пользователя. Возможно ли как-то, когда страница загружается, попросить пользователя дать разрешение на воспроизведение аудио на сайте, и только после явного разрешения пользователя загрузить страницу, а затем вызывать этот код в JS, когда мне нужно?

заголовок противоречит последней фразе вопроса.

поправил спасибо.

Не уверен, что правильно понимаю ваш вопрос, и особенно последний абзац, но... Если вы "согласие пользователя" видите как однократное действие для внесения куки и последующего autoplay, то — увы. Но, если вы каждый раз собираетесь заставлять пользователя взаимодействовать со страницей, то без проблем (по крайней мере пока ещё).  При любом явном клике на странице можно запустить воспроизведение. Т.е., согласно вашему ТЗ, ответ — да, можно.

я имел ввиду когда пользователь открывает первый раз страницу, тогда 1 раз получаем согласие на воспроизведение звука, потом уже не спрашивая пользователя в любой момент проигрываем звук. На бэкенде происходят какие то события, и этот звук нужен чтобы уведомить пользователя об этом.

Хоспаде, как же всё смешалось в доме Облонских... то вам плеер с автозапуском нужен, то уведомления. Уведомления могут приходить и без плеера. Конфиденциальность и безопасность > Звук > Уведомления. Причём об этом явно можно спросить пользователя. Кстати, подкинули вы мне тут мысль, и надо будет попробовать, что можно сделать со звуком на уровне сокетов, да base64 никто не отменял.

Попробовал запускать через сокеты. Увы, суть та же, работает, но только после взаимодействия со страницей. Так что у вас, если хотите чтобы пользователь без явного взаимодействия со страницей, мог слушать музыку сфер только один выбор — уговорить его получать уведомления.

В каком браузере пробовал?

Ваш код хочет воспроизвести звук по ходу загрузки страницы. В этом случае никак не успевает пользователь взаимодействовать со страницей.
В отличии от этой ситуации, по программным событиям для уведомлений можно автоматом воспроизводить аудио, но всё упирается в это взаимодействие, оно должно произойти до того, как произойдет первое программное событие. Достаточно кликнуть в любом месте страницы.
Ну, специально для тех, кто ставит минусы, если они не поняли, что я хочу сказать, вот простой пример программного события с уведомлением - выдача звукового сигнала по истечению пяти секунд после загрузки страницы:
setTimeout function(){
  audio.play();
}, 5000);

Если пользователь успеет в течении первых пяти секунд после загрузки страницы кликнуть в любом месте страницы, команда сработает. Если нет - выдаст ошибку. Один раз кликнуть не так уже сложно.

задача такая что на бэкенде может произойти какое то событие в любой момент времени, и нужно уведомить пользователя звуковым сигналом об этом, те звук должен быть воспроизведен без его взаимодействия.

Есть такой хороший браузер - Microsoft Edge, он позволяет сделать то, что Вы хотите. Во всех остальных к сожалению разработчики уже больше пяти лет бьются над тем, чтобы это было сделать невозможно. Причиной послужили множественные жалобы пользователей на то, что фоновый звук начинает играть неожиданно, когда типа колоннки включены на полную громкость, а в соседней комнате кто-то спит.
